# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, host

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306) in D:\Hosting\8224951\html\word\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1141
>
> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: No connection could be made because the target       machine actively refused it. in D:\Hosting\8224951\html\word\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1141

I always get this error while trying to connect to my wordpress website.
I've searched everywhere and can't seem to find a solution.

here's my wp_db file contains on like 1141.

```
    if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
        $this->dbh = mysql_connect(':/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock', 'ShiftBusinessSol', '123456!');
    } else {
        $this->dbh = mysql_connect(':/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock', 'ShiftBusinessSol', '123456!');
    }
```

as for config i have this:

```
 /** The name of the database for WordPress */
 define('DB_NAME', 'ShiftBusinessSol');
/** MySQL database username */
 define('DB_USER', 'ShiftBusinessSol');
/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '123456!');
/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1:3306');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

The error

> [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively

in Wordpress means that the setting of `DB_HOST` is wrong.

```
/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1:3306');
```

However in *your* case there is a special note to make:

The file `wp-db.php` has been modified from original Wordpress that does not allow you to configure your database host via standard Wordpress configuration any longer.

So in your case contact the vendor that provides you the modified version of Wordpress and discuss the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check from your command line is your database is listening to any port or not.

Answer (score 0):

Connect Error (2002) No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. I have re set up windows and tried just about everything .... wamp just stopped working.... now matter how many times I download and install wamp on my win 10 I seem to get two errors  the 2002 error and msvcr120.dll error ... I didn't have this problem 2 weeks ago .... please make suggestions

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you shouldn't make problem too complicate, let 's use wamp instead of xampp or just buy a hosting then you can have more time to focus to development.